# VeeValidate doesn't follow the rule that I set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I receive some data from server that results in different form fields. I'm trying to do the following:

```
<vs-input
          v-if="data.type === text "
          :name="data.field"
          :label="data.display_name"
          v-model="content[data.field]"
          class="w-full mb-base"
          v-validate="{'required': data.required === 1}"
          :type="data.type"
          :danger="errors.items.length > 0"
          :danger-text="errors.items.length > 0 ? 'The field is required' : ''"
          >
          </vs-input>
```

So basically eventually I receive 4 inputs (I'm using vuexy to display them). What I want to do: if an element gets the data.required parameter,which is equal to 1, it should be validated, if not - no validation is needed. But I end up having the validation on all of the inputs! I dont' know what to do and what I am doing wrong - for instance, applying

```
:class={green:data.required === 1}
```

Worked like a charm, but with VeeValidate - no luck :(

I'm using the 2 version (2.2.8, to be precise)

Comment: pls give this a try `v-validate="{ rules: { required: data.required === 1 } }"`

Comment: @ShivamSingh unfortunately, the same result :(